# list length from StreamBuilder?

Tags: dart, flutter

In the header of my flutter app, I want to display a `Chip` with the number of items in the list displayed in the body.  The build method of the body is using a `StreamBuilder` to create the list.

The problem is that the length of the list isn't known until after the `AppBar` is built and the `StreamBuilder` finishes building the list.

Since I can't call `setState`() from within the build function, how can I get the value in the `AppBar` to update after the `StreamBuilder` is finished building the list?

I'm working through [this example](https://github.com/bizz84/multiple-counters-flutter/blob/d4b899a03ca64a3c2259323a1b034f41658eea13/lib/pages/streams_page.dart#L32).  Here's the code snippet:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Streams'),
        elevation: 1.0,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: _buildContent(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: _createCounter,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContent() {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Counter>>(
      stream: stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ListItemsBuilder<Counter>(
          items: snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data : null,
          itemBuilder: (context, counter) {
            return CounterListTile(
              key: Key('counter-${counter.id}'),
              counter: counter,
              onDecrement: _decrement,
              onIncrement: _increment,
              onDismissed: _delete,
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I've found a way around it by creating a second `StreamBuilder` just to update the `Chip` in the `AppBar`.  Is it a good practice to have multiple `StreamBuilder`s watching the same stream?